# Could someone explain this code?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, constructor

A friend of mine, wrote some code in my application (which I couldnt figure out, and it works). But I don't really understand what it's doing. Could someone please explain it?

#### AddForm:

```
    public AddMember(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainForm = mainForm;
    }
```

#### MainForm:

```
    private void NewMemberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddMember addMember = new AddMember(this);

        addMember.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I don't understand the **bold** parts:

> public **AddMember(MainForm mainForm)**
>
> AddMember addMember = new **AddMember(this)**;

Comment: Have you asked your friend?

Comment: I presume he's opening a new form and passing a reference from the current one. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: He is just setting your current instance of main form to MainForm reference

Comment: when you click `NewMemberButton` in your main form new  `AddMember` form is constructed and it saves reference to your mainForm retrieving it by `this` passed to constructor

Comment: @millimoose: If you're removing "don't be harsh" just so you can be harsh (in that comment that was just deleted), you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm removing it since a question should stand on its merit, not on how well the OP can plead that their case is special. (I do so frequently since it's mostly clutter.)

Comment: @millimoose: Then leave it at that. Editing it out, and *then* posting a comment that you know will get flagged for that reason isn't going to help make your case.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't particularly care about my "case". I did the edit to defluff the question. I added the comment to accompany my downvote with pointing the OP at a resource that I genuinely thought was relevant, given the level of competence *displayed in the question*. If someone had a problem with the tone and that it was followed by that edit, that's their prerogative - I don't feel attached to my comments in general and that one specifically to protest the removal, I just don't like my motives being misconstrued.

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> public AddMember(MainForm mainForm)
> ```

Since there is no return type specified, `AddMember` is actually a constructor - and the type must therefore be `AddMember`. The constructor accepts a parameter of type `MainForm`, presumably a reference to a form instance.

> ```
> AddMember addMember = new AddMember(this);
> ```

This creates a new instance of type `AddMember`, passing in the current instance (presumably a `MainForm`) as the value, and assigns this new `AddMember` reference to the variable called `addMember`.

What was unclear?

Answer (score 2):

```
public AddMember(MainForm mainForm)
```

Looks like a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx) that accepts a `MainForm` object called `mainForm`.

Inside the constructor,  you create a new instance of `AddMember` and pass in the current instance as a parameter (`this`).  This newly created object is called `addMember`

Answer (score 1):

> `public AddMember(MainForm mainForm)`

It is  [Instance Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of class `AddMember`, taking parameter `mainForm` as instance of `MainForm`  which executes when you create instance of that class i.e.`AddMember` class.

> AddMember addMember = new AddMember(this)

This creates instance of class `AddMember` which passes current class as its argument. It looks like your object creation happening in `MainForm` class.

Answer (score 1):

The `AddMember()` method is the constructor for an `AddMember` class which just happens to live within the `AddForm` file.

```
AddMember addMember = new AddMember(this);
```

is creating an instance of the AddMember class and passing a reference to the enclosing object into it.